# Format for specifying exception type in Should -Throw -ExceptionType

Tags: pester, pester-5

I'm upgrading some very old tests to work with Pester 5.  Back in the day `Should -Throw` did not support specifying the exception type that should be thrown so I rolled my own assertion.  Now I want to replace my home-made assertions with `Should -Throw -ExceptionType`.  I can find very little online about how to specify the exception type to go with `Should -Throw -ExceptionType`, however.

The Pester [Assertions Reference](https://pester.dev/docs/assertions/) page doesn't mention `-ExceptionType` at all.  The only reference I've found is to an old blog post, https://jakubjares.com/2017/12/19/using-should-throw/, which includes the code:

```
Should -Throw -ExceptionType ([ArgumentException])
```

Could someone please explain the format?  What do the `([...])` do?  And how can I specify a non-standard exception type?  I want to check for a `ParameterBindingValidationException`.  I've tried

```
Should -Throw -ExceptionType ([System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException])
```

and

```
Should -Throw -ExceptionType ([System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException, System.Management.Automation])
```

and

```
Should -Throw -ExceptionType ([System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.3.7.500, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35])
```

but I just get an error similar to the following when I run the test:

> RuntimeException: Unable to find type [System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException]

If I replace the exception type with

```
Should -Throw -ExceptionType ([System.ArgumentException])
```

Pester then seems to recognise the exception type I specified.  I get the following message:

> Expected an exception with type [System.ArgumentException] to be thrown, but the exception type was [System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException, System.Management.Automation, Version=7.3.7.500, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35].

So I'm confused as to how I should specify the exception that should be thrown.

Comment: Thanks @MarkWragg.  I tried it but got a different error.  I've edited the question to include the new result.

Comment: Yep sorry. deleted my comment as it was bad advice. Seems your original syntax is correct. I've posted an answer, seems to work for me as long as you test for the exact right type name.

Comment: I'll remove my edit to the question to avoid complicating it unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by using your last example, and then getting it to check for the type the error returned (which I now realise was slightly different to what you were getting):

```
{ get-service -blah test } | Should -Throw -ExceptionType ([System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException])
```

It seems for an invalid parameter the correct type to test for is `[System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException]`.

Edit: I should add, this works for me under PowerShell 7. Might be different for you if you're using Windows PowerShell.

Comment: That worked, thanks.  Strange that if I put in a different exception type, such as `System.ArgumentException`, it tells me the actual exception type is `System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException` (note the ...Validation...) but it won't accept that as the expected exception type.  Nonetheless, you got it working.  Thank you very much, I'd been stuck on that for hours!

Comment: My pleasure, just got lucky that PS7 spat out the right type!